# Is there a common naming convention for private virtual functions in C++?

Tags: c++, coding-style, naming-conventions

Is there a common naming convention for private virtual functions in C++? I've seen conventions such as `do_something(...)`, `something_vfunc(...)`, etc. Which convention is usually used in C++ projects?

Comment: `mvp_doSomething()`. member, virtual, private :)

Comment: No, there is a whole plethora of conventions.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore mvp_hwnd_getHandle()... The rage, the uncontrollable rage... jons34yp - stick to the same conventions as variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention used in the standard (e.g. among many [`std::numpunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct)) is that `do_something` is a `protected` `virtual` method, and `something` is a `public` non-`virtual` method that calls it.

Answer (score 1):

i use the prefix `dyn_`. so you might see:

```
class t_type {
public:
    /* ... */
    void method() {
        this->dyn_method();
    }

private:
    virtual void dyn_method() const = 0;
};

class t_subtype : public t_type {
public:
    /* ... */
private:
    virtual void dyn_method() const {
        ...
    }
};
```

as far as a common one - i am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

There are many conventions I'm sure. I tend to use a trailing `Impl` or `_impl` depending on the convention of the rest of the method name. So `ComputeFoo` calls `ComputeFooImpl` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Different teams and people use different standards. My personal is not to add any special prefixes or suffixes. Name should represent what this function does. IDE will help you to see whether it is private or protected, virtual or not. And yes, it is a good taste to make virtual function private or protected, but if you are adding new function only to follow this principe — think twice.

Comment: I agree. Modern IDE's are good at providing hints about code. Adding suffixes and prefixes to variable names is old-school. It makes them (IMHO) uglier and more difficult to interpret.